# Check if integer is in between of any integer pair of a two-dimensional array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

**Given:**

Element int to match: `4200`

2-dimensional array column (int[][]): `{{1000,3000},{4000,4500},{8000,9000}}`

**Desired output:** records where `4200` is found `between/range in ANY` of the `integer pair` in the multidimensional array.

**sample ideal output:**

```
4200 = true
900 = false
4501 = false
8000 = true
```

**What I have so far is:**

```
SELECT schedule."hours" FROM public."Schedule" as schedule
  WHERE 4200 between schedule."hours"[1][1] and schedule."hours"[1][2];
```

The challenge for me is that I need to check it in all the arrays. As what I've done is only to match it on the first integer pair of the multidimensional array.

**EDIT ANSWER:** If anyone else has the same concern as mine.

I sent this link to one of my colleagues and he understood my concern quickly and pointed out to use **generate_subscripts** instead of manually listing the index on my where clause **(between schedule."hours"[1][1] and schedule."hours"[1][2])**

**generate_subscripts** is exactly what I needed to list indexes and use it on my where clause.

Comment: I am sure enough I have described my question well on the title. This is not a homework question. I am purely knew to SQL as I only have frontend development experience. I am not sure how to better expand my question:

On schedule table, I have a 2 dimensional array column "hours".
I want to filter schedule records where a specific hour matches in the range of any pair found in hours column.

Comment: How are your arrays stored in the database?

Comment: @LajosArpad as int[ ] [ ]
::
ALTER TABLE public."Schedule"
ADD COLUMN "hours" int[][];

Comment: Closing the question was ill-considered. The question is well-worded, though it is about the wrong approach to the problem.

Comment: @lemongrab - As compensation for the hasty closure of the question, see [this fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=27946ec332f519cf51e7180eb91d3fa5)

Comment: @klin I agree that choice of data format is not ideal, I'll have to try and discuss this with the other people involved in the project. The fiddle you've attached is wonderful and works as what I was trying to do. I already have a running query that also solves my problem. Now, all I need to figure out on my own is that which is faster and maintainable. Thank you!